# How to replace an image of a link button on click event using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I m new in jquery.. 
I have following link button in view page

```
<div id = 'image'>
<%= link_to_function image_tag("play_images.jpeg",:width => 30, :height => 30,:align => 'left', :title => 'Play'),:id => 'play'%>
</div>
```

what will be jquery for this..

```
jQuery("#play").click(function() {
       //What to write here to replace image of button
```

});

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("#play").click(function() {
       //What to write here to replace image of button
   jQuery(this).css('background-image','your_image_url');
});
```

Comment: Hey I dont want to change its background image or CSS. Its not working any more.

Comment: Please check the console,weather there is any error related to this

Answer (score 0):

```
link_to_function image_tag
```

will generate an image tag. You just need to change the src attribute for the image.

```
$("#play").click(function() {
   this.src = 'path_to_your_image.jpg';
});
```

Hope this helps.